# PHP Installed in IIS, but showing error while running codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis

I have installed PHP and MySQL on IIS Server. It's giving this error.

Warning: include(D:***\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\CANONICA\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 268

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'D:***\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\CANONICA\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 268

Tried enabling all extensions also.

Installed PHP version 8.0

Database Getting connected and getting inserted also, but the above warnings are showing at the top of the page.

Tried with the empty controller, then also showing the same. anybody of you knows this to sort out?

Comment: Essential PHP restriction on path, https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: @LexLi , I have gone through this one, and i found its all same.. Any other option?

Comment: I never used php and IIS together, but based on other similar situation, it seems some permission issue, can you change folder permission under "security" tab and check if the issue continues?

Comment: @ThiagoRyuuga It works well. It was permission issue itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If setting the permission in IIS publisher, then it will work.

When we are setting the domain inside IIS, grant all required permissions. then this error will not show.